# CSS - Prevent Submit Button From Getting Focus

Tags: css, focus, styling

In Opera when a text field is focused, the submit button gets an ugly black border.

You can see this in a screenshot.
[image]

In the bottom of the image the textarea is focused and submit button looks awful. How can I prevent this using CSS?

**UPDATE:** the CSS for the button is

```
.uiGreenButtonOuter {                     
 border: 1px solid  #234723;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.uiGreenButtonInner {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: block;
 background: #3E7E3E;
 padding: 4px 6px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #6AB76B #3A763B #3A763B;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #234723;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.uiGreenButtonOuter:hover .uiGreenButtonInner {
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #4C9B4C;
}

.uiGreenButtonInner:focus{
 outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle, using opera you can see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/SZTxH/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433623/default-submit-button-style-for-form

Comment: Keep in mind, if you remove that focus border you severely reduce usability and accessibility. Not everyone can use a mouse and this makes keyboard navigation difficult.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :focus or :blur pseudo-classes to do the trick. We need the code to understand the exact problem.

eg.

```
textarea:focus {/* your css here */}
```